# No (full) administrator access on backend Magento 2

Tags: magento2, admin, backend, security, page

After couple of weeks holiday i came back and stared in to an problem. I don't have access to the backend of Magento 2. My colleges have access and can do their work (product, inventory and ordermanagement), but full administrator access isn't possible with my account.

When I created the Magento 2 environment, i've made an back-up admin account. Also with this seperate account, i can't get in. This seperate back-up admin account isn't used for the last months..

I'am getting the following page after giving in the credentials and press login:
[image: issue]

Hope anyone can help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the issue a couple days ago.

The security page is the "Account Settings" page, my Mageplaza 2Factor extension was cousing this issue. I've a password expiration policy from 180 days, the 180th day has passed and the site where forcing me to "Account Settings" to change my password.

After creating a tirth admin account by Magento CLI and disabling the extension from Magaplaza, the problem was solved.